# how to go to previouse lines of an algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an algorithm that I want go to previouse lines of it in MATLAB.

for example: 4-14- Correct the value of i from Equation i = i+1 and go to step 3–4. 
Or I want to do: Step 5-Correct the value of k from the equation k = k + 1. If k>a-b, go to step 6; otherwise, go to step 4.

in this cases how can I go to step 3-4 from 4-14 ? or in second example how can I go to Step 4 after Step 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to say without more information, but why don't you structure your code in different functions and use ["switch case"](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) to control the logic? This would make your code more modular, easier to read and debug (which usually a nightmare in codes using "goto" clauses). 
In any case, there is at least one ["goto" function](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26949-matlab-goto-statement) in the Matlab file exchange repository.